# Getting incremental commit number

Tags: gitlab-ci, git-rev-list

I am using

```
"git rev-list --count HEAD"
```

to get the current commit number in the GitLab-CI/CD .yml file.

But to my surprise, every time I commit some code, the above number keeps on **decreasing** instead of **increasing** sequentially.

Please let me know, if I am missing some steps or tags, which will make the incremental HEAD.

Comment: Are you running this command locally with the full repo checked out? Or are you running this in GitLab CI? Are the results of the command the same in GitLab CI as they are locally?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely caused by your git clone depth configuration in GitLab CI. By default, GitLab uses a shallow clone ([by default](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#limit-the-number-of-changes-fetched-during-clone) a depth of `50`) when fetching your repository for CI jobs. That means that the result of `git rev-parse --count` will only show the count of commits up to the configured depth.

As you make more commits, revs related to your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file fall out of the depth 'window' and therefore, the count for a specific file *may* decrease in your pipelines with each successive commit.

You can fix this by configuring your [GitLab project settings](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#limit-the-number-of-changes-fetched-during-clone) to ensure a shallow clone is not used (or that the depth is otherwise sufficient for your use case). Alternatively, you can run a command like `git fetch --unshallow` inside of your GitLab job before running `git rev-parse` to ensure you're operating on a complete copy.